# SQL stored procedure combine result

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have written two SQL Server stored procedures

For example:

```
create PROCEDURE query1
AS
SQL code here...

create PROCEDURE query2
AS
SQL code here...
```

Now I can call them individually using the following command, and the returned value is the following.

```
exec query1

Study   availability
ACR        99.97%
```

Now I want to combine these stored procedures and get the results in one shot, like :

```
exec query1
exec query2
```

and it give result something like following but somehow its now working its giving me syntax error. How do I combine two stored procedures and get results in one report?

This is T-SQL query

```
Study   availability
ACR       99.97%
FOS       87.88%
```

Comment: Providing some code in addition to the syntax error may be helpful for people reading your post

Comment: What is consuming this data? A reporting tool, such as Crystal Reports?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since they both return the same column headings/data types I recommend combining the 2 separate queries into a single query and use UNION ALL.

EX:

```
SELECT 'ACR'      AS Study,
        SomeField AS Availability
FROM SomeTable1

UNION ALL 

SELECT 'FOS'      AS Study,
        SomeField AS Availability
FROM SomeTable2;
```

It's hard to give more specific advice without seeing your actual Stored Procedures, but this is definitely much clearer than having 2 separate procedures. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 6):

You can't call them the way you describe (ie exec query1 exec query2). Here is one alternative assuming each proc returns a single value:

```
declare @result as table (
ACR float,
FOS float
)

INSERT INTO @result(ACR)
exec query1

INSERT INTO @result(FOS)
exec query2

SELECT ACR,FOS from @result
```

Comment: I have tried to run your code and its giving error incorrect syntax at double. I am running this code on MS SQL 2008 server.

Comment: @Satish Corrected my answer. I had an error on the syntax. Sorry about that.

Comment: Thanks! now i am getting error "Column name or number of supplied values does not match table deinition." any idea?

Comment: two one for "study name" and another for "availability". you can see that in my question.

Comment: @lcarus - If you look at my initial question i have mention i need result in study and availability format. query1 gives me result and query2 give me result and i want them in single page when i will generate report so i will appear in single page. first column1 "Study" and column2 "availability" in percentage of that study. did you get what i am trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1):

You can try that:

```
exec query1; exec query2
```

But be aware that the result is not combined, you just get the result of both SPs as separate result sets.

Comment: In your syntax it just giving me single result of first query. look like its not executing second query. I need separate result.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your code, you can insert the results of each SP into a table, and then UNION them together to get the single result set you are looking for - but this often can be slower if it's a lot of rows since you are making copies of the results instead of just streaming them out to the client.  And it breaks the ability of the optimizer to combine things across the boundary, since it has to write them to the temporary tables.

If the procs aren't complex, I would consider making them into views or inline table-valued functions.  These can be easily combined by other routines like views, functions or procedures and make things a bit more modular.

Comment: I tried following it doesn't work exec query1 UNION exec query2

Comment: @Satish Right, you cannot do that with procs.  That's why I said you have to output them to a table and then select the union.  And also why I suggest using other database constructs if possible - for instance with table-valued functions can do: SELECT * FROM TVF1(params) UNION TVF2(params)